# Как преобразовать .exe файл в .bin файл?

Tags: binary, executable

Как преобразовать .exe файл в .bin файл?

Comment: Добрый день, постарайтесь описывать более конкретно. Вопросы, как правило, закрывают из-за длины содержимого и проблем с качеством - особенно, когда трудно понять, в чем именно суть вопроса.

Comment: @void, нормальный вроде вопрос

Comment: @КузинАлександр Измените расширение файла на .bin. Обдумайте это, может все-таки недостаточно информации в вопросе?

Comment: Нет какого-то единого формата bin. Поэтому не понятно что конкретно вы хотите - может просто переименовать файл, а может извлечь из него какую-то часть, положить в файл с таким расширением.